# Solve My Circular Reference via Non-Iterative Calculation?

Tags: excel, circular-reference

**Update - Simplified Even More:**

Just in case people are getting overwhelmed, here's a super simple version of my problem:

[image: Excel Screenshot - Circular Reference Problem Simplified]

Please write me formulas for Columns C, D, and E where:

- Column C

  - If Column B is 0, then if Column A is 1, put 1, else 0.
  - If Column B is 1, then if Column A is 1 and Column E is 0, put 1, else 0.
- Column D

  - If Column C is 1, put 1, else 0.
- Column E

  - Sum of Column D.

But do so without circular references.

**Problem:**

I have just created a circular reference on my Excel sheet, and I understand why it is circular. When I go to the circular reference cell, then do Formulas tab, Evaluate Formula button, it seems to evaluate as intended. Therefore, I'm hoping someone could propose a non-iterative calculation solution for me.

**Context:**

I am trying to resolve medical claims rejected as being duplicates.

I first check to see if another claim appears to be a duplicate, then, if no duplicate claims were found, I check to see if a rejected claim is duplicating against itself.

**Excel:**

[image: Excel Screenshot - Circular Reference Problem]

Here you see a simplified image of two claims:

- Column S has criteria for the claim data (out of screenshot) that would qualify each claim as a duplicate.
- Column AF, Primary Cause, checks if Column S (and other similar classification columns I have hidden for purposes of illustration) is a 1. If yes, it says 1, otherwise 0.
- Column AG counts how many 1s there are in Column AF.

Right now, I changed the formula for Column S, and it yields a circular reference warning for Columns S, AF, and AG, for rows that have 0 in Column R. The formula in Column S (using S3 as an example) is:

```
=if(and(or($R3=0,$AG3=0),[the other claims data criteria that would mark the row as a duplicate]),1,0)
```

The circular reference occurs when Excel is calculating a row with a 0 in Column R, 0 so far in Column AG, and that would be a 1 in Column S (but isn't yet because it hasn't been calculated). In this case, both $R3=0 and $AG=0 evaluate as True in the Column S formula, but once the evaluation finishes and Column S is marked as one, then Column AF becomes 1 and Column AG becomes 1, and then the OR() in Column S goes from being (True, True) to (True, False). This doesn't change the net outcome of the OR(), but it is making Excel worried.

**Restate the Problem:**

Given all this, and assuming that iterative calculation is not the optimal solution (please let me know if it is), how would I fix this issue? I have looked through several SO Excel Circular Reference posts already and will keep looking.

Edit: Made a correction to the description of Column AF and the description of why a circular reference occurs.

Comment: Why not make truth tables? -- there are 2^4 = 16 possible values in columns A, B. If the values in C,D,E are functions of those values, circular references are not required since it is known that the basic logical operators (built into Excel) are adequate for expressing any truth table.

Comment: You seem to be saying that D = C, no?

Comment: D = C, but only in the simplified example. In my real sheet, there are 6 Cs, only one of which can be 1, and if any of them are 1, then D is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to my previous self-answer, my circular reasoning was giving incorrect answers and should not have been used.

Comment: (I will accept this if no one posts a better answer in a day)

Answer (score 0):

You have a Liar's paradox in the case that all 4 cells in A2:B3 are equal to 1. The formula you have in Column C depends on A,B (which are the same in both rows) as well as the sum of column C (which is what E holds). Thus -- the two values in column C are the same according to your own rules. If that value is 0, then E is 0, hence the value is 1 after all. If the value is 1, then the sum is 2 (not 1) hence the value is 0 after all. Thus the values in C are 0 if and only if they are 1. Unless it is impossible for all 4 values in A,B to be 1 at the same time, you have an inconsistent set of specifications.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I probably over-simplified in my effort to draw an answer. Though your assumptions were good for my over simplified example, my real life example precludes some of them. For example, the rows will always have some of both 1 and 0 in column B (1 for the rejected claims themselves and 0 for the possible duplicates). Next, column E is allowed to be more than 1, no problem. I just test if it is 0 or not. Finally, I am trying to see if possible duplicates meet the Column C criteria while keeping the rejects as 0, then, if no duplicates meet it...

Comment: ... see if the rejects themselves meet the Column C criteria. So there would never be a 0 for both lines of Column C. Thank you again for your efforts, sorry I did a poor job communicating!